# What default value for File type formcontrol in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

Angular 14v use typed forms. The form looks like this:

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

export interface FileForm {
  file: FormControl<File>;
}
```

Init:

```
return this.formBuilder.group({
    file: new FormControl<File | null>(null, { validators: [Validators.required] })
  }
);
```

Is there better options for init value than 'null' ? (It is required control).

I tried to init with null value.

Comment: It is a headache for me as well, if you already found any better solution please share. I had to use File[] type with empty array as a default value, however that forced me to update my model interface which is annoying.